# How to update parent scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I tried to update my parent scope from the child controller using two solutions but I can't make it work. `apply()` didn't work

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerA">
   <div ng-show="tab_selected == 1">Content1</div>
   <div ng-show="tab_selected == 2">Content2</div>
   <div ng-controller="ControllerB">
      <span ng-click="updateScope()"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
app.controller('ControllerA', ['$scope', 
  function ($scope) {
     $scope.tab_selected = 1;
}]);

app.controller('ControllerB', ['$scope', 
  function ($scope) {
     $scope.updateScope = function(){
        $scope.tab_selected = 2;
        // $scope.apply(function(){  $scope.tab_selected = 2; }); 
     }
}]);
```

Comment: `$scope.$parent.tab_selected = 2;`

Comment: Various ways, but one easy way is to use an object or array in the parent scope (this will be instantly available across both parent and child scope - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972976/angular-js-propagate-child-scope-variable-changes-to-parent-scope

Comment: For the Love of god :( this is the 10000nth , ALWAYS USE A DOT in angular $scope properties

Comment: @xe4me What do you mean ?

Comment: @Steffi it's been suggested by angular team and of course its true that always use a DOT , that means to stick anything to $scope, E.g $scope.myVariable , instead of using a primitive variable , alvays use an object , like : $scope.variables.myVariable !! (You see DOT ? - that means always define objects instead of primitives)

Comment: If you look into angular questions , almost half of them will be solved(or has been solved) with using object instead of primitives; that's embarassing

Answer (score 1):

Controllers have separate scope but there is a few way to communicate

- $broadcast the event to parent scope
- use service for two-way data binding i.e. http://plnkr.co/edit/Vqk1Fe?p=preview
- with scope inheritance i.e. http://plnkr.co/edit/7wcMnJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can't update primitive attributes in the parent object, only object attributes. So you need to use:

```
$scope.someObject= {};
$scope.someObject.tab_selected= 2;
```