# Angular JS parent scope is not updating child scope

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have some nested menu where I am trying to change the color of a child scope from parent but its not working. Here is the simplified code.

```
.directive('botMenuClick', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope,ele,attrs){
            ele.bind('click', function(){
                 if(ele.attr('homeBtn')==='true'){
                    scope.$parent.setDisplay = {'color': '#fff'} // this applies to all children but not the one which is set in else condition
                 }else{
                     scope.setDisplay = {'color': 'green'}
                 }
                 scope.$apply();
            }); 
        }
    }
})
```

So, once I get in to the else condition and that menu color is changed to green then no matter what it won't change to white even if I go in the above homeBtn condition.

Comment: are you trying to access parent scope from child scope or child scope from parent scope?

Comment: I am setting setDisplay style from its own scope then change it latter from parent.

Answer (score 2):

That's because that's how prototypal inheritance works. If a child object sets a property with the same name as a property on a prototype then the child is actually creating a new property in itself which hides the parent property. From [this mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

"Setting a property to an object creates an own property. The only exception to the getting and setting behavior rules is when there is an inherited property with a getter or a setter."

My assumption is that the UI element is binding to the child scope property, which doesn't exist until it is set by the `else` condition, so up until that point it's looking up the prototype chain for the value of `setDisplay`. As soon as the `else` condition fires `setDisplay` gets set on the child scope, hiding the prototype value for the rest of eternity.

Comment: but setDisplay is already set in html in ng-style like this


<div class='bottomSubMenuHolder' ng-show='showSubMenu' ng-style="setDisplay">
                            <div ng-repeat='bottomSubMenu in bottomMenu.subMenu' class='bottomSubMenu'>{{bottomSubMenu.subMenuLabel}}</div>
                        </div>

Comment: Binding to a scope value in HTML is not setting anything. Setting an HTML binding lets the `$compile` service know which JavaScript properties on the `scope` to bind to. All declaration and modification of properties happens in JavaScript.

Comment: Please read this question to get more context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972976/angular-js-propagate-child-scope-variable-changes-to-parent-scope?rq=1

Comment: I got the Plunker link. There are two menus the first one works but I want the menu 1 to close all menu. I tried the second approach so that I can detect the menu 1 and perform other task but one I modifying scope I can't change the it again from parent. here is the link http://plnkr.co/edit/vBnXZNIc8aEizpGxXhhK?p=preview