# AngularJS - old value of property sent to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've the following controller in AngularJS:

```
$scope.model = null;
$scope.load = function() {
     $http.get(someUrl).success(function (data) {
                $scope.model = data;
     }
}

$scope.save = function() {
      $http.post(url, $scope.model)
           .success(function (data) {
                // some handle
            }).error(function () {
                 // some handle
            });
}
```

The model scheme:

```
$scope.model.PayDate === "2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z"
// deserialized from request, date is in ASP.NET format
```

Next, the `PayDate` prop is attached to some control (via `ng-model`), that sets the new date in javascript DateTime class. 
So, the value of changed `PayDate` before sending to the server looks like:

[image: value]

Unfortunately, when request is sent to the server, the value of `PayDate` is the old one:

[image: val]

Why the old value of `PayDate` is sent instead of current stored in the model?

**EDIT:**
The workaround is to convert JS date to string before send:

```
$scope.model.PayDate = moment($scope.model.PayDate ).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
$scope.save();
```

Then, new value is send in a request.

Of course, I would like to fix the issue instead of converting each date field into string just before posting.

Comment: Is the control creating a child scope?

Comment: How can I check that?  I use https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker as date time picker.

Comment: I've had problems due to timezone stuff before.  Not sure if this is a similar problem though.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743058/how-to-access-the-angular-scope-variable-in-browsers-console

Comment: Is the html `ng-model="PayDate"` or `ng-model="model.PayDate"`?

Comment: @BenFelda like docummention points out, the field is bound as `data-ng-model="model.PayDate"` - Is far as I'm concerned, `PayDate` would indicate to `$scope.PayDate`.

Comment: @MarioLevrero it looks like that control creates own child scope.

Comment: @pwas  Yep, just making sure.  Just because your javascript shows what's on `$scope` doesn't mean you bound it correctly in your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having an issue with the timezone you're in (poland UTC+2 ?)

You are dealing with a Javascript `Date` which is in your current TimeZone GMT+2
So you'll see `Thu Apr 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200` but once it sends it back to the server its sent as an ISOString

`new Date("2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z")`

output: `Thu Apr 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (YOUR TIMEZONE)`

`new Date("2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z").toISOString()`

output: `"2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z"`

So those 2 dates are actually the same

Comment: It sounds very reasonible. I will take a look.

Comment: Confirmed - the problem was a timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to inject $timeout in your controller.
So timeout does a digest cycle first, and then post your data..

```
$scope.save = function() {
  $timeout(function(){
    $http.post(url, $scope.model)
       .success(function (data) {
            // some handle
        }).error(function () {
             // some handle
        });
    });
};
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, the same problem occurs.

Comment: But for me, the problem was gone

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your directive is creating a child scope with its own variable, that does not modify the parent's one. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972976/angular-js-propagate-child-scope-variable-changes-to-parent-scope) with the same situation.

** Update after the JS String update **

From [documentation](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)

> Working with ng-model
>
> The angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker directive requires ng-model and
>   the picked date/time is automatically synchronized with the model
>   value.
>
> This directive also plays nicely with validation directives such as
>   ng-required.
>
> The angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker directive stores and expects the
>   model value to be a **standard javascript Date object**.

Try to use a DateObject instead of a String

So, instead of

```
$scope.model.PayDate === "2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z";
```

Use

```
$scope.model.PayDate === new Date("2015-04-29T22:00:00.000Z");
```

Comment: Maybe but I 've only one controller in my html. So it looks like that the plugin for date time picker has a bug inside.

Comment: BTW. Converting Date to string fixes the problem (see my edit). So maybe scopes are build properly?

Comment: But Doc says is waiting for a Date Object. I've update my answer

Comment: I know, i use Date from JS.  That snippet shows only the value that is got from server. Then it is coverted to JS Date. As you can see in my quesion, The value before post in JS Date.